# Why is 4/14 is 0.00000 in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float val = (4 / 14) ;
    printf("%f\n",val);
}
```

I don't know what the problem is but it returns 0.00000 instead of 0.285714...

Comment: Since both `4` and `14` are *integers*, then `4 / 14` is an integer division with an integer result.

Comment: Because you're dividing two integers, which produces an integer (0), which you only then convert to a float.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the behavior of integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division)

Comment: And to rectify it, you can write `float val = (float)4 / 14;` or `float value = 4.0 / 14;`